# DynamoDB - Scan not returning all items

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am facing some troubles when scanning my table in DynamoDB in my Node.js function.

When I scanning at the function I got 2 rows, but when scanning at AWS console I am getting 3 rows.

Follow below the code:

utilsAWS scan function:

```
scanDocuments(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var docClient = new this.AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

      console.log(`Querying ${params.TableName}...`);

      docClient.scan(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(
            "Unable to query. Error:",
            JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
          );
          return reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Query succeeded.");
          return resolve(data.Items);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

//consuming scan function

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'minha-redacao-redacoes',
    FilterExpression: "#e = :cpfAluno",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#e": "cpfAluno",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":cpfAluno": `8509754....`
    },
  };
  try {
    const res = await utilsAWS.scanDocuments(params);

    console.log(res.length); //2

  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
```

But look at the AWS console:

[image: scan by console]

The row id: `f3ebb776-13eb-4395-884e-e81f23044ca1` is not found when scanning by the `node.js` function. To solve partially the problem I've created the `f3ebb776-13eb-4395-884e-e81f23044ca1_manual` document.

Any one knows a definitive solution to this issue?

Comment: In your code sample you specify `ExpressionAttributeValues` with a value of `8509754....` while your screenshot displays `8509754` (the dots are missing). Is this a typo?

Comment: I am just hidden the full number of the brazilian document to post here. The values are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that all 3 records actually satisfy the filtering criteria, your should check `LastEvaluatedKey` attribute of the response.

Despite the small number of items involved, there is no guaranty that a `scan` operation will return all matching elements in the first response. The contract is:

- if: `LastEvaluatedKey` is empty, then you are on the last *page* of results
- else: you need to repeat the scan operation with a parameter `ExclusiveStartKey` in order to resume the scan.

More info [in the official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination).

Comment: Ok! I will check this option here... :D

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm! :D Thank you so much!